# Strip quotes and spaces from a variable

Tags: python, join

I want to create a variable [Word] that contains a word from a list of letters but does not include any brackets, spaces or commas.

Here's where i have gotten to:

```
Letters = ["u", "i", "p","a","o","g", "h","j","k","l","z","x","v","b"]

FirstLetter = -1
SecondLetter = 'o'
ThirdLetter = 'a'
FourthLetter = 'l'
Endletter = 0
while FirstLetter < 13:
    FirstLetter = FirstLetter +1
    Word = (Letters[FirstLetter], SecondLetter,ThirdLetter,FourthLetter,Letters[Endletter])
    print(Word)
```

The output of the first line is:

```
('u', 'o', 'a', 'l', 'u')
```

I want:

```
uoalu
```

Sorry if this is already answered I've tried a heap of suggestions on here but cant get it

Comment: You're not stripping anything. You're trying to concatenate a bunch of pre-defined strings...

Comment: `print(''.join(Word))`

Comment: I don't consider the "duplicate question" a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join a string of characters into a single string, you should use [`join()`](https://pythonbasics.org/join/).

```
Word = "".join((
   Letters[FirstLetter], 
   SecondLetter,
   ThirdLetter,
   FourthLetter,
   Letters[Endletter],
 ))
```